# How to get unique number of rows from the secondary table

Tags: mysql, database

```
create table pro_category (id primary key, product_id int, category_id int)
insert into pro_category (1, 1, 1)
insert into pro_category (1, 1, 2)
insert into pro_category (1, 2, 1)
insert into pro_category (1, 2, 1)
```

How to get unique number of rows from the secondary table (e.g. in the above case there are 2 product id's involved so I would like to get an answer of 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [count(distinct)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct)

```
select count(distinct product_id) from pro_category
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT product_id) FROM pro_category
```

This will return 2